# Sqoop import mappers failed but sqoop job is showing running

Tags: hdfs, sqoop, netezza

I have written a Sqoop import program to import data from  Netezza using where clause, when there is syntax error in where clause, the mappers generated by Sqoop are throwing Netezza level syntax error and hanging.
How do I capture these scenarios and fail my Sqoop import job.

Answer (score 0):

Have added driver option --driver org.netezza.Driver to the sqoop import command, and its failing the sqoop import if there are any syntax errors in the query generated.
Since we are specifying the driver, sqoop import is using jdbc rather than external table with direct option.